# Extracting time to re-join

Tags: mysql, sql, r, dplyr

I have a table structured as follows, which contains information about club memberships

```
id  start       end          cancelled
1   2020-01-01  2020-12-31   2021-01-10
1   2021-02-01  2022-01-31   NA
2   2020-01-01  2020-12-31   NA
3   2020-01-01  2020-06-30   2020-07-01
3   2020-07-10  2021-01-09   2021-01-31
3   2021-02-02  2021-08-01   NA
```

I am interested in members that re-joined afterwards. For the above data, for the entire period, `id 1` did this once, `id 2` did not, and `id 3` did so twice.

Ffor each time that this occurred, what was the time between their membership ending, and them rejoining ? For the above data, this would be:

```
id  rejoin_date time_to_rejoin
1   2021-01-31  22 days 
3   2020-07-10  9 days
3   2021-02-02  2 days
```

For R:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), start = c("2020-01-01", 
"2021-02-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-07-10", "2021-02-02"
), end = c("2020-12-31", "2022-01-31", "2020-12-31", "2020-06-30", 
"2021-01-09", "2021-08-01"), cancelled = c("2021-01-10", NA, 
NA, "2020-07-01", "2021-01-31", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

For SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dt` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start` TIMESTAMP,
  `end` TIMESTAMP,
  `cancelled` TIMESTAMP NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `dt` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `cancelled`) VALUES
  ('1', '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', '2021-01-10'),
  ('2', '2021-02-01', '2022-01-31', NULL ),
  ('2', '2021-01-01', '2020-12-31', NULL ),
  ('3', '2020-01-01', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-01'),
  ('3', '2021-02-10', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-31'),
  ('3', '2021-02-02', '2021-08-01', NULL )
```

I would be happy with answers that use either R (ideally using dplyr) or SQL (MySQL)

Comment: If SQL, what database?

Comment: Why is 3's second rejoin date different than your sample data?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry that was a typo

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and then filter:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(start, prev_cancelled) as num_days_since_cancel
from (select t.*,
             lag(cancelled) over (partition by id order by start) as prev_cancelled
      from t
     ) t
where prev_cancelled is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e5d43aa75bd1fb9fd533a75f09cd813) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you (+1) this looks very promising but I can't get it to work without error. Would you be able to check it, vs the SQL CREATE I have added to my question. I had guessed that the sub query should have been `from <tablename>` rather than `t`

Comment: @JoeKing . . . I fixed the logic for the difference (between date and the previous cancel) and added a db<>fiddle with the data from the example in the question.  It returns exactly the specified results.

Comment: Thank you. I have just accepted this answer. Actually I have a follow-up question related to an edge case that this code doesn't work for. In case you have time to take a look, I'd be very grateful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752879/difficulty-with-variable-lag-length

Answer (score 1):

First, change to `Date` class, nobody should ever try to calculate date-differences on `character`.

```r
dat[,-1] <- lapply(dat[,-1], as.Date)
```

### base R

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$id, function(z) {
  if (nrow(z) == 1) return()
  data.frame(id = z$id[1], rejoin_date = z$start[-1],
             time_to_rejoin = as.numeric(z$start[-1] - z$cancelled[-nrow(z)], units="days"))
}))
#     id rejoin_date time_to_rejoin
# 1    1  2021-02-01             22
# 3.1  3  2020-07-10              9
# 3.2  3  2021-02-02              2
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    rejoin_date = start[-1],
    time_to_rejoin = as.numeric(start[-1] - cancelled[-n()], units="days")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id rejoin_date time_to_rejoin
#   <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
# 1     1 2021-02-01              22
# 2     3 2020-07-10               9
# 3     3 2021-02-02               2
```

or

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    rejoin_date = start[-1],
    time_to_rejoin = as.numeric(start - lag(cancelled), units="days")[-1]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, .(rejoin_date = start[-1],
          time_to_rejoin = as.numeric(start[-1] - cancelled[-.N], units="days")), by = .(id) ]
#       id rejoin_date time_to_rejoin
#    <num>      <Date>          <num>
# 1:     1  2021-02-01             22
# 2:     3  2020-07-10              9
# 3:     3  2021-02-02              2
```

Comment: Thank you (+1) Please could you add a little commentary for the `dplyr` solution that explains the `summarize` step ?

Comment: Quick follow-up, if a member has more than 1 concurrent unexpired membership, I believe your `dplyr` results in a row with `NA` for `<num>`, which seems perfectly OK because I can just remove it with `drop_na()`. Does that make sense to you ?

Comment: I guess, I hadn't considered that a possibility. If that works, stick with it.